# PostgreSQL update with no old binaries

Tags: linux, postgresql

Recently I updated an old server instalation, Gentoo linux distro.

There I had PostgreSQL 12 installed and after the emerge --sync and the emerge world I ended with PostgreSQL version 13 and 14 installed and the version 12 got completly removed with exception of the data directory (/var/lib/postgresql-12/data) so all my databases are still there (at least technically).

Now when I tried to run the pg_upgrade I have no bin files for 12 so I can't execute the command. I tried the command but I have to path to provide to the -b flag.

Any other way to migrate the database? or I'm stuck to re-install version 12?

I also tried to point the version 14 to the data directory but when I tried to start the server I got (as expected):

```
2022-06-06 11:04:04.127 -05 [12970] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2022-06-06 11:04:04.127 -05 [12970] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 12, which is not compatible with this version 13.5.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked to see whether the Postgres version 14 instance has the data in it? Also a more complete definition of '...my PostgreSQL got updated from 12 to 14,...` would be helpful. Add as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Hi, thanks for the response, I'll try to update the question with more info

Comment: So have you looked to see if the data is in either the 13 or 14 instance? Do you have a `pg_dump` backup of the database?

Comment: Nop, the data is only on the 12 instance, and I can't find any recent pg_dump, since this is not a production server, but have some development data that I want to recover.

Comment: Then you are going to have to reinstall Postgres 12.